# Could not find the partition for host when accessing tfs project

Tags: tfs

We had TFS 2013 installed on a server. Our server crashed and we lost all the data. The only thing we could recover was TFS database `.mdf` and `.ldf` files. So I installed and configured new TFS. The name of the TFS project and database is the same as the old one. Then I detached TFS new database and attached the old recovered database in SQL Server Management Studio. Now when I want to access my TFS project in browser I get the following error:

`TF400876: Could not find the partition for host 24e7791a-9e93-4021-b6b8-92abe5206045.`

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply attached the old recovered database.

> To restore data from the original deployment of Team Foundation
>   Server, you must have a complete set of data backups for the SQL
>   Server databases. If the data was encrypted, you must also have the
>   encryption key and its password.

According to your description, your scenario should be [Restore data to a different server than the current one for TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance), you need to follow the article step by step. Especially for [remapping the DBs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance#step-9-redirect-team-foundation-server-to-remote-collection-databases).

Comment: I don't have configuration database. I've lost everything. I have just collection database. Will this solution solve the problem?

Comment: @Beginner Generally, to [Move a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-project-collection) you must detach the collection to backup the collection DB in previous TFS, then restore to the new TFS. It's not available for you because the recoved DB is the original DB but not the basic detached backup DB.  I have no experience on only backup the collection DB manually with the solution mentioned in above annwer, you can have a try with it.